# How is a method resolved when using callvirt in the CLR?

Tags: .net, clr, cil, internals

Is it done at compile time? Because the index into the MethodTable of the method to call could be determined at compile time.

Or ist it done at runtime?

And what is the method token argument to callvirt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done a [blog post](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/simonc/archive/2010/11/05/95541.aspx) about how callvirt works at runtime.

At compile time, the argument to the `callvirt` instruction takes a concrete `MethodDef` or `MemberRef` token, referring to the 'base' method to call (this defines the method arguments, among other things)

At runtime, as part of doing type initialization, the CLR works out which methods override each other, and assigns a slot in the `MethodTable` vtable for each virtual 'base' method. Each type then fills that slot with a pointer to whatever actual method implementation should be used for virtual calls to that base method for instances of that type. That is then used to do the virtual call, as described in my post.

Comment: At the time of a virtual call with `callvirt`, how is this assigned slot then found? Just for my understanding: Say I would like to interpret (instead of JIT compiling) the `CIL` code, then somehow I must have a **fast** way to find this slot. Of course, a JIT compiler can determine this once and then produce native code with a concrete index.

Comment: Well, the CLR knows which vtable slot corresponds to which method, so it knows which slot to use, presumably storing this information in some sort of hashtable for lookup on the signature (parameters + name)

Answer (score 0):

When you have virtual method or Instance method and you compiles them. 
Your method will have callvirt token and will be called by CLR as callvirt, unless static method will have call token and will be called directly.

Callvirt will led the method to be called as virtual at runtime.

At runtime, CLR will examine your method whether its object has been instantiated. And CLR also examine whether your method has been overriden by its derived type. If it is not overriden, your method will be called.
If Yes, then its derived's method will be called.